# Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 update fail

Tags: package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

I’m using Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-58-generic x86_64) to run a headless server for our home network.  During a recent maintenance session I noticed that I could upgrade to a 20.04 version of Ubuntu Server after updating the existing system.  When I ran the command to update the system I encountered an error, see code...

I’m only somewhat proficient at the terminal, and wondered if anyone could help me to understand the right commands/process to correct these errors?
Thanks…

```
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them. lk@lkserver:~$ apt list --upgradable Listing... Done shim/xenial-updates 15+1552672080.a4a1fbe-0ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 15+1533136590.3beb971-0ubuntu1] wireless-regdb/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 2020.11.20-0ubuntu1~16.04.2 all [upgradable from: 2018.05.09-0ubuntu1~18.04.1] lk@lkserver:~$ sudo apt upgrade Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
```

Reading state information... Done Calculating upgrade... Done The following packages have been kept back: shim The following packages will be upgraded: wireless-regdb 1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded. 6 not fully installed or removed. Need to get 0 B/10.6 kB of archives. After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y (Reading database ... 106889 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack .../wireless-regdb_2020.11.20-0ubuntu1~16.04.2_all.deb ... Unpacking wireless-regdb (2020.11.20-0ubuntu1~16.04.2) over (2018.05.09-0ubuntu1 ~18.04.1) ... dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/wireless-regdb_2020.11.20 -0ubuntu1~16.04.2_all.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite '/lib/crda/pubkeys/sforshee.key.pub.pem', which is also in package crda 3.18-1build1 Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/wireless-regdb_2020.11.20-0ubuntu1~16.04.2_all.deb E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: What release are you running?   I see lots of *xenial* (16.04) mentioned in your pastes, plus if you want to upgrade to the next release you should be fully-upgraded on your current release, and 18.04.5 is the latest *bionic*, but you mention 18.04.3 as if you've not applied all updates.  Why are there *xenial* packages mentioned if you're using *bionic*?   (I would for sure check your sources, and what you're actually running)

Comment: Thanks... Originally installed as 16..04, then upgraded to 18.04 when that release became available. My intent was to update fully in 18.04 to then be able to upgrade directly to 20.04